# make netcat listen for multiple UDP packets

Tags: netcat

If I run a simple UDP listener like this:

```
nc -l -u -p 1234
```

Then I appear to only get the first inbound UDP packet. For example if I run:

```
$ echo abc | nc -u localhost 1234
  ["abc" appears in output of server as expected]

$ echo abc | nc -u localhost 1234
read(net): Connection refused
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

using a timeout of zero (0)

"Server":

```
nc -kluvw 0 localhost 9000
```

"Client":

```
echo -e "all"     | nc -vuw 0 localhost 9000
echo -e "the"     | nc -vuw 0 localhost 9000
echo -e "udp"     | nc -vuw 0 localhost 9000
echo -e "packets" | nc -vuw 0 localhost 9000
```

Result:

```
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 9000 [udp/*] accepted
all
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 9000 [udp/*] accepted
the
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 9000 [udp/*] accepted
udp
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 9000 [udp/*] accepted
packets
```

tested with:

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-23-generic-pae #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:19:09 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The "Server" line fails for me. It complains that -w must be greater than 0 and that -k is not supported in UDP mode except with --exec and --exec-sh. no big deal I can set -w to 1 but not sure about the -k error.

Anyone else seeing that?

Comment: @Dan : Yes, `-k` is not supported with UDP in the "classic" version, or in `ncat`. And `-w0` is also only supported in the OpenBSD version. See also my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that may help you: [netcat: Strange behaviour with UDP – only receives first packet sent](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/07/30/netcat-strange-behaviour-with-udp-only-receives-first-packet-sent/).

> At this stage I wasn’t sure what to do but Nathan pointed out that if I made use of timeouts on the client and server then it would be possible to send multiple UDP packets.
>
> I restarted the netcat server but this time with a 1 second timeout:
>
> ```
> $ nc -kluvw 1 localhost 9000
> ```
>
> And then started sending UDP packets from a netcat client also with a 1 second timeout:
>
> ```
>  $ echo -e "all" | nc -vvuw 1 localhost 9000
>  Connection to localhost 9000 port [udp/cslistener] succeeded!
>  $ echo -e "the" | nc -vvuw 1 localhost 9000
>  Connection to localhost 9000 port [udp/cslistener] succeeded!
>  $ echo -e "udp" | nc -vvuw 1 localhost 9000
>  Connection to localhost 9000 port [udp/cslistener] succeeded!
>  $ echo -e "packets" | nc -vvuw 1 localhost 9000
>  Connection to localhost 9000 port [udp/cslistener] succeeded!
> ```
>
> And the netcat server now receives all of them:
>
> ```
> $ nc -kluvw 1 localhost 9000
> XXXXall
> XXXXthe
> XXXXudp
> XXXXpackets
> ```

This was an interesting problem, hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

For monitoring an UDP port, you can try

```
netcat -lzu -p 9000

# -z, --zero                 zero-I/O mode (used for scanning)
```

This works in my GNU netcat 0.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a port, and always send from that port.

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696956/111036), after a listening UDP port got it's first packet, it will only accept additional input if it comes from the same sending port.

So, given a sending port, a listening port and a listening host:

```sh
send_port=7777
listen_port=8888
host=127.0.0.1
```

And a listener started with :

```sh
nc -lu -p $listen_port
```

**The sender must then use the `-p` option to always use the same source port**. This will work and print all 4 lines on the listener :

```sh
for c in {1..4}; do
  echo "line $c" | nc -u -w 0 -p $send_port $host $listen_port
done
```

Also, note that different versions of netcat have different rules about their options:

- the original netcat (`netcat-traditional` in Debian-based distributions) doesn't support a timeout of 0 (`-w 0`), so you need to use `-w 1` instead.
- [Nmap's](https://nmap.org/ncat/) `ncat` doesn't either, but supports fractional timeouts like `-w 0.1`
- In listener mode, the `-p` before the listening port is only needed in the original `nc` v. 1.10. Other versions just take the last argument as the listening port. But all accept it also as `-p $listen_port`.

Answer (score 0):

I currently get:

Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: UDP mode does not support the -k or --keep-open options, except with --exec or --sh-exec. QUITTING.